# Using regex in java 1.4

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex to valid a string which should contain
"A - Z", "a - z", "0 - 9", "-" , "_", "/" , "." , "%" , and ":"(period) characters only.

I have written code as below:

```
import org.apache.regexp.RE;

 private static boolean checkInvalidCharacters (String identity){
        RE re = new RE("(\\w%-/:.)");
   if (!re.match (identity)){
           return true;         
       }
       return false;
   }
```

I am not sure why this does not work?

Apart from letters and digits special characters required are  - / .  % : _

Comment: Why use Java 1.4? It's been out of date for a decade.

Comment: Yeah correct. Its just that our company does not want to upgrade :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
"^[\\w/.%:\\-]+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
[-\\w/.%:]+
```

Instead of using `org.apache.regexp.RE` you can use Java `String` API to validate:

```
private static boolean checkInvalidCharacters (String identity) {
   return !identity.matches("[-\\w/.%:]+");
}
```

Comment: @Jens: That's not true, inside character class dot doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. We are using java 1.4 light version. unfortunately i cannot use String API to match regex.

Comment: You can still use the correct regex I provided in my answer above.

Comment: No when i tried ur regex i got syntax errors Syntax error:

Comment: `code` Bad character class
    [junit] org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Bad character class
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.characterClass(Unknown Source)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.branch(UnknownSource)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.expr(Unknown Source)
    [junit]  at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.compile(Unknown Source)

Comment: ok try: `RE re = new RE("[\-a-zA-Z0-9_/.%:]+");` btw Java 1.4 also had `String#matches` API